# How to make recursion using only lambdas in Racket?

Tags: recursion, lambda, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I need some help trying to figure out how to make the code below recursive using only lambdas.

```
(define (mklist2 bind pure args)
  (define (helper bnd pr ttl lst)
    (cond [(empty? lst) (pure ttl)]
          [else (define (func t) 
                   (helper bnd pr 
                         (append ttl (list t))
                         (rest lst)))
           (bind (first lst) func)])
    )
  (helper bind pure empty args))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given a sample `fact`orial program -

```scm
(define fact
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (fact (- n 1)))))) ;; goal: remove reference to `fact`

(print (fact 7)) ; 5040
```

Above `fact` is `(lambda (n) ...)` and when we call `fact` we are asking for this lambda so we can reapply it with new arguments. `lambda` are nameless and if we cannot use top-level `define` bindings, the only way to bind a variable is using a lambda's *parameter*. Imagine something like -

```scm
(lambda (r)
  ; ...lambda body...
  ; call (r ...) to recur this lambda
)
```

We just need `something` to make our `(lambda (r) ...)` behave this way -

```
(something (lambda (r)
  (print 1)
  (r)))

; 1
; 1
; 1
; ... forever
```

**introducing U**

This `something` is quite close to the `U` combinator -

```scm
(define u
  (lambda (f) (f f)))

(define fact
  (lambda (r)     ;; wrap in (lambda (r) ...)
    (lambda (n)
      (if (= n 0)
          1
          (* n ((r r) (- n 1))))))) ;; replace fact with (r r)

(print ((u fact) 7))

; => 5040
```

And now that recursion is happening thru use of a parameter, we could effectively remove all `define` bindings and write it using only `lambda` -

```scm
; ((u fact) 7)
(print (((lambda (f) (f f))  ; u
         (lambda (r)         ; fact
           (lambda (n)
             (if (= n 0)
                 1
                 (* n ((r r) (- n 1)))))))
        7))

; => 5040
```

**Why U when you can Y?**

The U-combinator is simple but having to call `((r r) ...)` inside the function is cumbersome. It'd be nice if you could call `(r ...)` to recur directly. This is exactly what the Y-combinator does -

```scm
(define y
  (lambda (f)
    (f (lambda (x) ((y f) x))))) ;; pass (y f) to user lambda

(define fact
  (lambda (recur)
    (lambda (n)
      (if (= n 0)
          1
          (* n (recur (- n 1))))))) ;; recur directly

(print ((y fact) 7))

; => 5040
```

But see how `y` has a by-name recursive definition? We can use `u` to remove the by-name reference and recur using a `lambda` parameter instead. The same as we did above -

```scm
(define u
  (lambda (f) (f f)))

(define y
  (lambda (r)      ;; wrap in (lambda (r) ...)
    (lambda (f)
      (f (lambda (x) (((r r) f) x)))))) ;; replace y with (r r)

(define fact
  (lambda (recur)
    (lambda (n)
      (if (= n 0)
          1
          (* n (recur (- n 1)))))))

(print (((u y) fact) 7)) ;; replace y with (u y)

; => 5040
```

We can write it now using only `lambda` -

```scm
; (((u y) fact) 7)
(print ((((lambda (f) (f f))   ; u
          (lambda (r)          ; y
            (lambda (f)
              (f (lambda (x) (((r r) f) x))))))
         (lambda (recur)       ; fact
           (lambda (n)
             (if (= n 0)
                 1
                 (* n (recur (- n 1)))))))
        7))

; => 5040
```

**need more parameters?**

By using currying, we can expand our functions to support more parameters, if needed -

```scm
(define range
  (lambda (r)
    (lambda (start)
      (lambda (end)
        (if (> start end)
            null
            (cons start ((r (add1 start)) end)))))))

(define map
  (lambda (r)
    (lambda (f)
      (lambda (l)
        (if (null? l)
            null
            (cons (f (car l))
                  ((r f) (cdr l))))))))

(define nums
  ((((u y) range) 3) 9))

(define squares
  ((((u y) map) (lambda (x) (* x x))) nums))

(print squares)
; '(9 16 25 36 49 64 81)
```

And as a single `lambda` expression -

```scm
; ((((u y) map) (lambda (x) (* x x))) ((((u y) range) 3) 9))
(print (((((lambda (f) (f f)) ; u
           (lambda (r)        ; y
             (lambda (f)
               (f (lambda (x) (((r r) f) x))))))
          (lambda (r)         ; map
            (lambda (f)
              (lambda (l)
                (if (null? l)
                    null
                    (cons (f (car l))
                          ((r f) (cdr l))))))))
         (lambda (x) (* x x))) ; square
        (((((lambda (f) (f f)) ; u
            (lambda (r)        ; y
              (lambda (f)
                (f (lambda (x) (((r r) f) x))))))
           (lambda (r)         ; range
             (lambda (start)
               (lambda (end)
                 (if (> start end)
                     null
                     (cons start ((r (add1 start)) end)))))))
          3)   ; start
         9)))  ; end

; => '(9 16 25 36 49 64 81)
```

**lazY**

Check out these cool implementations of `y` using [lazy](https://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/index.html)

```scm
#lang lazy

(define y
  (lambda (f)
    (f (y f))))
```

```scm
#lang lazy

(define y
  ((lambda (f) (f f)) ; u
   (lambda (r)
     (lambda (f)
       (f ((r r) f))))))
```

```scm
#lang lazy

(define y
  ((lambda (r)
    (lambda (f)
      (f ((r r) f))))
  (lambda (r)
    (lambda (f)
      (f ((r r) f))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

In response to @alinsoar's answer, I just wanted to show that Typed Racket's type system can express the Y combinator, if you put the proper type annotations using [`Rec`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html#(form._((lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt)._.Rec))) types.

The U combinator requires a [`Rec`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html#(form._((lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt)._.Rec))) type for its argument:

```
(: u (All (a) (-> (Rec F (-> F a)) a)))
(define u
  (lambda (f) (f f)))
```

The Y combinator itself doesn't need a [`Rec`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html#(form._((lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt)._.Rec))) in its type:

```
(: y (All (a b) (-> (-> (-> a b) (-> a b)) (-> a b))))
```

However, the definition of the Y combinator requires a [`Rec`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html#(form._((lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt)._.Rec))) type annotation on one of the functions used within it:

```
(: y (All (a b) (-> (-> (-> a b) (-> a b)) (-> a b))))
(define y
  (lambda (f)
    (u (lambda ([g : (Rec G (-> G (-> a b)))])
         (f (lambda (x) ((g g) x)))))))
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this Alex. I don't spend enough time with typed racket

Comment: actually in my mind I thought about modifying `omega = ((λ(x)(x x)(λ(x)(x x))` and having it compute recursively the function you need...  But yes, omega is not by itself a fixed point combinator but can compute any recursive function.  Is `Y` the simplest fxed point combinator that is able to compute any recursion ?

Comment: @alinsoar what can O compute? it diverges, so it seems it can't compute anything. `O => O`. and the term in your comment has two unbalanced open parentheses, so, it's unclear what it's supposed to be.

Comment: @WillNess adding some mode parameters instead of only X and adding some terminating conditions instead of (x x), etc...

Answer (score 1):

Recursion using only lambdas can be done using [fixed point combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Recursion_and_fixed_points), the simplest one being [Ω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Standard_terms).

However, take into account that such a combinator has a type of infinite length, so if you program with types, the type is recursive and has infinite length.  Not every type checker is able to compute the type for recursive types.  The type checker of Racket I think it's [Hindley-Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) and I remember typed racket it's not able to run fixed point combinators, but not sure.  You have to disable the type checker for this to work.

Comment: The type checker of Racket is not Hindley-Milner. AFAIK the question was about standard untyped Racket, not Typed Racket. And the typechecker of Typed Racket isn't Hindley-Milner either, IIRC it can express the Y combinator, though only with type annotations. But I suppose I have gone off on a tangent irrelevant to original question

Comment: how is `Ω` a fixpoint combinator? it's not `Ω f = f (Ω f)`, but  `Ω f = Ω f`.

Comment: @WillNess I though `Ω=((λ(x)(x x)(λ(x)(x x))`.

Comment: you have two unbalanced parens there, so it's not clear what exactly you had in mind.

Comment: @WillNess ((λ(x)(x x))(λ(x) (x x)))

Comment: well, that's Ω, and that's what I referred to in the first place. It reduces to Ω, which in turn reduces to Ω, etc. etc. this means Ω f = Ω f, not f (Ω f) as any fixpoint combinator is supposed to be.