# How to implement a fast type inference procedure for SKI combinators in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, combinators

How to implement a fast simple type inference procedure for [SKI combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) in Python?

I am interested in 2 functions:

1. `typable`: returns true if a given SKI term has a type (I suppose it should work faster than searching for a concrete type).
2. `principle_type`: returns [principle type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_type) if it exists and False otherwise.

```
typable(SKK) = True
typable(SII) = False # (I=SKK). This term does not have a type. Similar to \x.xx

principle_type(S) = (t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t3
principle_type(K) = t1 -> t2 -> t1
principle_type(SK) = (t3 -> t2) -> t3 -> t3
principle_type(SKK) = principle_type(I) = t1 -> t1
```

Theoretical questions:

1. I read about [Hindley–Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system). There are 2 algs: Algorithm J and Algorithm W. Do I understand correctly that they are used for more complex type system: System F? System with parametric polymorphism? Are there combinators typable in System F but not typable in the simple type system?
2. As I understand, to find a principle type we need to solve a system of equations between symbolic expressions. Is it possible to simplify the algorithm and speed up the process by using SMT solvers like [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3)?

My implementation of basic combinators, reduction and parsing:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import typing
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True)
class S:
    def __str__(self):
        return "S"

    def __len__(self):
        return 1


@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True)
class K:
    def __str__(self):
        return "K"

    def __len__(self):
        return 1


@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True)
class App:
    left: Term
    right: Term

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.left}{self.right})"

    def __len__(self):
        return len(str(self))


Term = typing.Union[S, K, App]


def parse_ski_string(s):
    # remove spaces
    s = ''.join(s.split())

    stack = []
    for c in s:
        # print(stack, len(stack))
        if c == '(':
            pass

        elif c == 'S':
            stack.append(S())
        elif c == 'K':
            stack.append(K())
        # elif c == 'I':
        #     stack.append(I())

        elif c == ')':
            x = stack.pop()
            if len(stack) > 0:
                # S(SK)
                f = stack.pop()
                node = App(f, x)
                stack.append(node)
            else:
                # S(S)
                stack.append(x)
        else:
            raise Exception('wrong c = ', c)

    if len(stack) != 1:
        raise Exception('wrong stack = ', str(stack))

    return stack[0]


def simplify(expr: Term):
    if isinstance(expr, S) or isinstance(expr, K):
        return expr

    elif isinstance(expr, App) and isinstance(expr.left, App) and isinstance(expr.left.left, K):
        return simplify(expr.left.right)

    elif isinstance(expr, App) and isinstance(expr.left, App) and isinstance(expr.left.left, App) and isinstance(
            expr.left.left.left, S):
        return simplify(App(App(expr.left.left.right, expr.right), (App(expr.left.right, expr.right))))

    elif isinstance(expr, App):
        l2 = simplify(expr.left)
        r2 = simplify(expr.right)
        if expr.left == l2 and expr.right == r2:
            return App(expr.left, expr.right)
        else:
            return simplify(App(l2, r2))

    else:
        raise Exception('Wrong type of combinator', expr)

# simplify(App(App(K(),S()),K())) = S
# simplify(parse_ski_string('(((SK)K)S)')) = S
```

Comment: Python might not be the best language for something like this. Haskell or SML might be a more natural choice.

Comment: @JohnColeman I need it for my Python implementation of SKI combinators. I saw a few implementations and all of them ware in Haskell. Not easy to understand if you don't have enough experience with Haskell (like me)

Comment: Uaskell is not the right language for this, Prolog is. It's very simple [to write it down](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/SKI-type-inf.pl) in it; SWI-Prolog can even infer the type of **Y**-combinator, and even of **YI**. Or course it works depth-first; you probably need to implement breadth-first search, or better, "diagonalized" ("dovetailing", "omega"-monad) search.

Comment: [this Python kanren implementation](https://github.com/pythological/kanren) seems to be interleaving (as expected), so it could fit your needs here.

Comment: @WillNess your comments are very helpful. I will try to implement in Python. Can you please explain: diagonalized, omega-monad and interleaving (is it breadth-first search) in Karen?

Comment: I'll try to add more details later. in the meantime, these terms are googlable, and "dovetailing" is in Wikipedia, I think... (interleaving turns `[1,2,...], [11,12,...]` into `[1,11,2,12,...]` instead of `[1,2,...,11,12,...]` and is applied pairwise when there's more than two lists). my comments are not as helpful as I'd like though. SWI Prolog does some magic which I don't exactly understand, automatically creating the equivalents of recursive types, as can be seen in the results for `s*i*i` (try `type(s*i*i, T), numbervars(T,2,_).` at the SWISH link).

Comment: see ["dovetailing" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)), it has great discussion and explanation exactly of what I meant. You can also check out this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848902/849891) which conveys the bare essence of (mini)kanren approach to logic programming. search for "interleaving" on that page for more. as for the `pythological` impl I also mention above, [its source](https://github.com/pythological/kanren/blob/main/kanren/core.py) has `from toolz import interleave`.

Comment: and here's the [toolz docs on `interleave`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.interleave). so in theory you could try coding it in Prolog style using `pythological/kanren`. But it probably won't be as simple as what I threw together in that link. (also, that SWI-Prolog "magic" I mentioned, probably has to do with "occurs check" and "cyclic terms", I think -- yet more googlable terms there ;)  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, maybe not the fastest (but reasonably fast if the types are small).

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


class OccursError(Exception):
    pass


parent = {}

Var = int


def new_var() -> Var:
    t1 = Var(len(parent))
    parent[t1] = t1
    return t1


@dataclass
class Fun:
    dom: "Var | Fun"
    cod: "Var | Fun"


def S() -> Fun:
    t1 = new_var()
    t2 = new_var()
    t3 = new_var()
    return Fun(Fun(t1, Fun(t2, t3)), Fun(Fun(t1, t2), Fun(t1, t3)))


def K() -> Fun:
    t1 = new_var()
    t2 = new_var()
    return Fun(t1, Fun(t2, t1))


def I() -> Fun:
    t1 = new_var()
    return Fun(t1, t1)


def find(t1: Var | Fun) -> Var | Fun:
    if isinstance(t1, Var):
        if parent[t1] == t1:
            return t1
        t2 = find(parent[t1])
        parent[t1] = t2
        return t2
    if isinstance(t1, Fun):
        return Fun(find(t1.dom), find(t1.cod))
    raise TypeError


def occurs(t1: Var, t2: Var | Fun) -> bool:
    if isinstance(t2, Var):
        return t1 == t2
    if isinstance(t2, Fun):
        return occurs(t1, t2.dom) or occurs(t1, t2.cod)
    raise TypeError


def unify(t1: Var | Fun, t2: Var | Fun):
    t1 = find(t1)
    t2 = find(t2)
    if isinstance(t1, Var) and isinstance(t2, Var):
        parent[t1] = t2
    elif isinstance(t1, Var) and isinstance(t2, Fun):
        if occurs(t1, t2):
            raise OccursError
        parent[t1] = t2
    elif isinstance(t1, Fun) and isinstance(t2, Var):
        if occurs(t2, t1):
            raise OccursError
        parent[t2] = t1
    elif isinstance(t1, Fun) and isinstance(t2, Fun):
        unify(t1.dom, t2.dom)
        unify(t1.cod, t2.cod)
    else:
        raise TypeError


def apply(t1: Var | Fun, t2: Var | Fun) -> Var | Fun:
    t3 = new_var()
    unify(t1, Fun(t2, t3))
    return t3


try:
    a = S()
    b = K()
    ab = apply(a, b)
    c = K()
    abc = apply(ab, c)
    print("#", find(abc))
except OccursError:
    print("# no type")

try:
    a = S()
    b = I()
    ab = apply(a, b)
    c = I()
    abc = apply(ab, c)
    print("#", find(abc))
except OccursError:
    print("# no type")

# Fun(dom=6, cod=6)
# no type
```

Comment: Why did you write `assert not occurs(t1, t2)` but not `if occurs(t1, t2): raise TypeError`?

Comment: @OlegDats the assertions are errors in the input program. The TypeErrors are errors in the type checker.

Comment: What is the difference between these errors? For example `SII` does not have a type. It creates an assertion error, meaning there is no type? Then TypeError is more like RuntimeError, meaning there is something wrong with the input data... ?

Comment: @OlegDats if I implemented this in a statically typed language, the TypeErrors would be type errors while compiling the type checker. The assertions would be during the type checker runtime.

Comment: @OlegDats **`SII`** really does have a type, a *recursive* type `t ~ (t -> a)`. For example, here's [a Typed Racket answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61800052/849891) that gives this type to it (as `U` combinator, `SIIx = xx = Ux`).

Comment: @OlegDats I replaced the asserts with a real exception to show what's going on. Failing an occurs check is the only way that Hindley–Milner fails on SKI combinators.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I have tested your answer and seems it works. May I ask you to add comments to your code (find, unify) and briefly explain the general idea of how and why it works? It could be useful for other people.

Comment: @OlegDats It's more or less straight out of this writeup: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Degrees_of_freedom_instantiating_the_rules